# Is there a graphic or dataset way to campare the performance of the main currencies over the years?

Tags: currency, historical-data, comparison

Is there  a graphic or dataset way to campare the performance of the main currencies over the years?

I mean a graph that allows to compare many currencies on the same chart, and not two currencies at time

Comment: Define "performance", please. That's not a word normally associated with currency.

Comment: I mean the trend of the exchange ratio

Comment: Historical exchange rates and graph paper (or general-purpose graphing programs, or graph support in spreadsheet programs) are fairly easy to obtain... plot it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @keshlam mentioned, [OANDA](http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates-classic) and many other websites offer daily histories of exchange rates for download.  I recommend downloading the history of each exchange rate you care about versus a common currency (such as USD).  Then use your favorite data analysis tool ([R](http://www.r-project.org/), [Excel](http://www.microsoft.com/), ...) to plot them all on the same graph with date on the X axis and value-in-USD on the Y axis.  (You might want to scale some of them first; KRW and JPY, for example, are worth so little in USD that you won't even be able to see their movements.)

Comment: If you don't want to pay for Excel.  Open Office has a spread sheet product as well.

Comment: Or LibreOffice as I think it's now called.

Comment: OANDA seems very good (+1), but is limited to 500 days and would like to analize last 10 years

Comment: I Googled "currency rates historical" and got a page full of sites that all look like they might have what you need for free.  Give them a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[MyCurrencyTransfer](http://www.mycurrencytransfer.com/currency-converter) offers really good historical currency information over a 12 month period, broken down by over 160 cross currency pairings.